# How can I tell if a string in python is either an int or float using if condition?

Tags: python

I am getting different strings, some are numbers, for example:  "1", "afd76", "dddd", "521129" and "0.1423105". I need to check if they are valid numbers before I can continue. In the above examples all are numbers apart from "afd76" and "dddd".

isdigit and isnumeric wont do because they can only verify if the string is an int, for example:

```
"3".isdigit() is true but "3.0".isdigit() is false
"3".isnumeric() is true but "3.0".isnumeric() is false
```

Is there any elegant way to do this check other than force casting and deciding what to do depending on the exception?

Comment: I'd probably use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: The most effective way is with a try except: `try: n=float(s); except ValueError: n=0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float

Answer (score 3):

You can try casting the string into float:

```
def is_number(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Examples:

```
>>> is_number('123')
True
>>> is_number('123a')
False
>>> is_number('123.12')
True
>>> is_number('3.0')
True
```